# find all pairs $(a,b)$ of real numbers so that for each $n, a F_n + bF_{n+1}$ is a fibonacci number

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, limits, elementary-number-theory

> Let $F_1 = F_2 = 1, F_{n} = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}, n\ge 3$ be the Fibonacci sequence. Find all pairs $(a,b)$ of real numbers so that $a F_n + bF_{n+1}$ is a Fibonacci number for all $n \ge 1$.

I think this question should have a similar solution to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952874/find-all-pairs-a-b-in-mathbbr2-such-that-af-n2bf-n12-is-a-membe). By induction, one can show that $F_k F_n + F_{k+1} F_{n+1} = F_{k+n + 1}$ for all $k\ge 1.$ But are the pairs $(F_k, F_{k+1})$ the only such pairs? It might be useful to use the well-known Binet formula for the Fibonacci numbers: $F_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (\phi^n - (1-\phi)^n), \phi = \dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\,\forall n\ge 1.$ Also, if a sequence of integers has a limit, that limit must be constant.

Suppose $a F_n + bF_{n+1} = F_{k_n}\,\forall n\ge 1.$ I think it might be useful to expand this equation out using the Binet formula and then multiply both sides by $\phi^{-n}$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24aF_%7Bn%7D%2BbF_%7Bn%2B1%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3AFibonacci&p=1), I found the AoPS thread [On Fibonacci Sequence](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h366952p2019625), where its part (a) is your question. The result is what you stated, plus $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. I took a brief look through its proof, with it appearing to be correct. Instead of me basically repeating what was written there, I suggest you read it yourself and, if you believe it's correct, perhaps then answer your own question.

Comment: Surely, $(-1,1)$ works. So if there is no positivity restriction, then the negative extension of Fibonacci numbers should be added to the answer list.

Comment: @dezdichado - nice thought, but since the question defines exactly what it means by the Fibonacci sequence, I doubt it would be acceptable. By that definition $(-1,1)$ doesn't work for $n=1$.